# Data Visualization Tool recomendations

Tags: visualization

I need a tool that lets me create a solution that fullfills the following requirements:

- Needs to be interactive and user friendly:  Possibility to apply filters, change dimensions, etc..
- Needs to be updated online: Must be able to process data in real time.
- Needs to be able to handle huge ammount of data and support big data technologies.

Bonus points for python or R libraries but its definetely not a must.

I was thinking on getting started with D3py or google charts but I dont know if they are the best options.

What would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tools/software are listed below. Most of these can do what you want but require input in other areas such as in development of a UI or the tool may have a learning curve to overcome.

- [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/): I guess this sets the benchmark. Really user friendly, has a large chart gallery and can process data in real time.
- [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/): Has two variants "server" and "cloud version". Can handle big data but may require a licence depending on your domain
- [D3](https://d3js.org/): A JS library for data viz and is light weight. User friendliness and interactive nature depends on how you design the UI. Can also display data in real time.
- [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/): Another JS library for web and mobile devices. Deals with data in XML of JSON format. Requires a licence.
- [Qlikview](http://www.qlik.com/us/): One of Tableau's competitors. Highly customisable, so there may be a learning curve to get accustomed with the tool.
- [Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/): Surprisingly good. Ticks all your boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If user friendly and interactive matter, then how about Tableau (or QlikView). You can work directly on the data and can connect to 'big data' sources. Also you can trigger R / Python scripts from there.

If you want something more customizes, then maybe Shiny.